# find command with subprocess not working with out Shell=True

Tags: python, find, subprocess, python-2.6

I have below lines in my code. I have embedded a short a line which fetches the list of files that are older than 10 mins. My sub process have been failing with few errors. It seems to work when I give Shell=True, but I read that it is a very risky to use that option and I am very new to the Python, Don't want to mess up with something I am not understanding. I have tried changing quotes with in and around that find statement, but its not helping me. can you please suggest how could I get the list of files using find command.
I have looked into other questions with these find and subprocess combinations, I did not find any wildcard directory matches. I could not find solution for this.

```
cmd = 'find /myapp/uat/aws/6.3/domains/*/appnodes/*/*/log/bwappnode.log -type f -mmin +10'

 apps_in_proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
```

Comment: Try passing `cmd.split()` instead of `cmd`?

Comment: Its not recognizing the pattern.
find: `/myapp/uat/aws/6.3/domains/*/appnodes/*/*/log/bwappnode.log': No such file or directory

Comment: @AK47 , Tried that as well, not working.

Comment: @AK47, I am listing the files in recursive directory structure and specifically looking for files older than 10 mins, find command is short and just does the job. So trying to use that command.

Comment: @VenuS also `Shell=True` is only dangerous if the script accepts some form of user input and runs the input through `subprocess.Popen()`, if you're not writing an interactive script and none of your commands are dynamically changed based on user input, it will be safe to use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it works with `shell=True`, and not without, that means that the pattern is expanded with `shell=True`.

To emulate this behaviour just use `glob.glob` and compose your command argument list like this:

```
cmd = ['find'] + glob.glob('/myapp/uat/aws/6.3/domains/*/appnodes/*/*/log/bwappnode.log') + ['-type','f','-mmin','+10']
```

Which could be written very easily in pure python:

```
import glob,os,time
current = time.time()
old_files = [x for x in glob.glob("/myapp/uat/aws/6.3/domains/*/appnodes/*/*/log/bwappnode.log") if current - os.path.getmtime(x) > 600]
```